# Split command and arguments, and put into variable in a bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, grep, variable

I have a script that repeats the same (very long) `grep` command many times. I want to make the script more readable by cutting the line length, so I tried to put parts of the command into variables.

This is the line (that repeats many times in the script, with different parameters):

```
rsync -av --delete -R --exclude=alternatives /etc/ /backup.raw/ | grep -E '^deleting|[^/]$' >> /var/log/rsync.log
```

That line works ok. What I did trying to abbreviate it, is:

```
_rscmd='rsync -av --delete -R'
_mn=/backup.raw/
_grep='grep -E "^deleting|[^/]$"'
_rslog=/var/log/rsync.log
```

so the "final" line could be:

```
$_rscmd --exclude=alternatives /etc/ $_mn | $_grep >> $_rslog
```

But that line fails on the `$_grep` variable. How can I write it right? I tried to use `"…"` and `'…'`, with no luck. Pay attention to the original grep command that works, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The splitting into different parts (command & arguments) does not work if
variables are used. Use `eval` for this case:

```
eval $_rscmd --exclude=alternatives /etc/ $_mn | eval $_grep >> "$_rslog"
```

In general, it is better to use *shell functions* or *aliases*
than using variables:

```
alias my_grep='grep -E "^deleting|[^/]$"'
...
... | my_grep >> "$_rslog"
```

Comment: perfect man! eval it's the solution! thanks!. A note: the first variable doesn't need for the eval command, that works ok without it. Thanks again!

Comment: @sergius yes, you are right. `bash` does not require `eval` there, but as e.g. `zsh` would need it, I added it.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way is to make only command's arguments as variable

```
_mn=/backup.raw/
_rscmdarg='-av --delete -R'
_greparg='-E "^deleting|[^/]$"'
_rslog=/var/log/rsync.log
```

as `$_rslog` is a file, and `$_mn` a dir, it is okay to keep them.

and the "final" line is:

```
rsync $_rscmdarg --exclude=alternatives /etc/ $_mn | grep  $_greparg >> $_rslog
```

Comment: I understand you, that's seems more clear. Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this that includes (IMHO) the best parts of the other two answers
is to write a shell function that embodies all the functionality that
you want to be invariant, and takes arguments
specifying the things that you want to be different on different instances:

```
my_rsync_grep() {
      rsync -av --delete -R "$1" "$2" "$3" | grep -E '^deleting|[^/]$' >> /var/log/rsync.log
}
```

and call it with the desired parameters:

```
my_rsync_grep --exclude=alternatives /etc/ /backup.raw/
```

This acts as if you had put the `rsync … | grep …` command
into a separate script.  (Except it isn’t a separate file, so you don’t have
the configuration management problem of keeping track of multiple files
or the logistic problem of how to invoke another script
(i.e., do you use `./` or not?),
and you don’t have any extra disk I/O every time you invoke the function.)

**Notes:**

- As a matter of readability and programming style,
  you might want to move the I/O redirection (`>> /var/log/rsync.log`)
  out of the function and apply it to each invocation:

  ```
  my_rsync_grep --exclude=alternatives /etc/ /backup.raw/ >> /var/log/rsync.log
  ```

  This makes it obvious to anybody who reads or maintains the script
  that that line is writing to a file.  However, it also makes it easier
  to inadvertently introduce inconsistencies into the script. 
  Of course, you can (and probably should) put the filename into a variable
  (e.g., `$_rslog`),
  to reduce the risk of having one line that writes to `/var/log/rsycn.log`.
- If you think that the function code is readability-impaired
  because it’s too long a line, you can break it into multiple lines. 
  Append a `\` to each line but the last:

  ```
        rsync -av --delete -R "$1" "$2" "$3" | grep -E \
                '^deleting|[^/]$' >> /var/log/rsync.log
  ```

  As a special case, if you break immediately after a `|`, `&&`, or `||`,
  the `\` is optional:

  ```
        rsync -av --delete -R "$1" "$2" "$3" |
              grep -E '^deleting|[^/]$' >> /var/log/rsync.log
  ```
- The function, as written above, assumes that it will always be invoked
  with exactly three parameters.  This assumption seems unrealistic. 
  To run the `rsync` command with any/all parameters passed to the function,
  use `"$@"`:

  ```
        rsync -av --delete -R "$@" | grep …
  ```
- If, for example, you wanted to change the function
  to take the `grep` argument as an argument, e.g.,

  ```
  my_rsync_grep --exclude=alternatives /etc/ /backup.raw/ (other arg(s)) '^deleting|[^/]$'
  ```

  you can do it like this:

  ```
  my_rsync_grep() {
        nargs=$(($#-1))
        rsync -av --delete -R "${@:1:nargs}" | grep -E "${@:$#}" >> /var/log/rsync.log
  }
  ```

  See the **Parameter Expansion** section
  of [bash(1)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?bash)
  for more information on `$@` and constructs
  like `${parameter:offset:length}`.

  Note: This syntax might not work in shells other than `bash`.